# Python using ternary operator in groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is there a way to use the ternary operator inside a groupby condition?Apparently this syntax is invalid.

```
d = {'name':['bil','bil','bil','jim'],
     'col2': ['acct','law', 'acct2','law'],
     'col3': [1,2,3,55],
     'col4': [1,1,1,2]

    }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df2[['col4']] = df2[['col4']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
df2.groupby(['name','col2'])['col4']\
    .max() if (.max()>30) else ''
```

Comment: You can wrap it in a function and use `.apply`

Comment: What is the final result that you want to obtain? It is very unclear what you are applying the condition to, in the first place (are you applying it to the `col4` or what?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* use a ternary, but I'm not going to show you that. Instead, here's a better alternative - mask the result:

```
v = df2.groupby(['name','col2'])['col4'].max()
v.where(v.gt(30), '')
```

Using `lambda`s inside `groupby` slows its operation down quite drastically.

Comment: Thats freaking awesome, thanks for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insist on using a ternary, the below would do:

```
def condition(row):
    return row['col4'].max() if row['col4'].max() > 30 else ''

ds = df2.groupby(['name','col2']).apply(lambda row: condition(row))
```